# Produce a download file from CGI in Lua

Tags: lua, cgi

I am writing a simple CGI program in lua. What I want to achieve is produce a response from CGI which enables a file to be downloaded from the browser. But I just can't print the data. I have no idea what's going on here. Here is the code below:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
print("Content-Length:" .. sys.getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"))
print("Content-Disposition:",'attachment;filename="backup.tar.gz"\n')
print("Content-Type:application/x-tar-gz\n\n")
file=io.popen("some command")
output = file:read('*a')
print(output)
--file:close()
```

The problem is I just can't print the output whose content is binary. I can see the type of output is string.

What is the problem? Please give some hints about it. Thank you.

**ADD** : I have no idea about this and Where is the issue. Let me put more info about the command I want run. But I don't think that matters.

1. Actually, I work in openwrt, the web server uhttpd. (No LuCI here)
2. The command is:sysupgrade -b - 2>/dev/null. This command is used to backup     the config file. I want to write a CGI to download the backup file from the web.
3. But I can not print the output to the server. Even in the terminal(in lua IDE) I cannot print out the output except one or two messy code. But I can write the output to a file in terminal. Maybe it has some relationship with the content of out.
4. When I print the content line by line, it prints some, but not all of it. After I download the file. I can't open it.

Comment: Does the length of the `output` value (`#output`) matches the size of the output produced by `some command`? When you say you can't print, what do you mean? Why are you not including Content-Length if you know the size of the output?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. The length is right. I mean the  print function just print  nothing out. But output is the string and the length is right.

Comment: wouldn't the second statement raise an error?

Comment: Don't run it as a CGI script; try running it locally and printing the content into a file, then check the content of the file. I don't see the issue with the code (other then several problems with the second line that is supposed to set Content length).

Comment: @PaulKulchenko I did that.  I found I can not print all  the output , which is about 5677B. What is the point of this? I have no idea about this.  But if I print it line by line,it works. when I run it in CGI, after I download the file, I can not open it, some errors says it is broken. But I can see the response text which is some messy code.  Is there any wrong with the http header settings?

Comment: @hjpotter92 You mean the function sys.getenv? This function will get the length of data transferred. That's ok. Apart from this, any issues?

Comment: No, @hjpotter92 meant that your second line is missing concatenation and closing bracket.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sorry for my carelessness. Typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Content-Disposition:",'attachment;filename="backup.tar.gz"\n')
print("Content-Type:application/x-tar-gz\n\n")
```

I think you have way too many new lines. First of all, you can newline in `Content-Disposition` and this is in addition to the newline that `print` adds, which ends the headers and makes `Content-Type` a part of the payload (which breaks the content). You also have two newlines in `Content-Type` where you only need one (as one is added by the `print` command).

I think something like this should work:

```
local file = io.popen("some command")
local output = file:read('*a')
file:close()
print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
print("Content-Length: " .. #output)
print("Content-Disposition: " .. 'attachment;filename="backup.tar.gz"')
print("Content-Type: application/x-tar-gz\r\n")
print(output)
```

Comment: It is supposed to work, but no. When I try to print  output in the terminal, it just give one or two messy code. Not all of the content. The .tar.gz file is empty with no data.

Comment: Ok, you can check how many characters are printed and deduce what character it stops on; then check that character in the original output of "some command". It may be useful information.

Comment: I have give the command which is **sysupgrade -b -** in openwrt. It produces a binary stream of tar.gz. I think some code prevents the print function printing continuously.  I don't know to handle this.  Even if I test some other plain text, I still can not open the tar.gz file. But I can open it as text. Why?

Comment: HTTP header uses CRLF `\r\n` instead of LF `\n`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, correct, although there is [Tolerant Applications](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.3) section that allows for a single LF. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Wandy, instead of printing `output`, try printing `:gsub(".", function(s) return ("\\%d"):format(s:byte()) end)`. This should convert all binary characters to their `\xxx` code and you will be able to see all of them. What is the length of `output` comparing with the length of command output when saved to a file?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff   I think "\n\n"  has the same effect as "\r\n" . And I have tested it. it seems no difference.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko It is a good idea.  But the stream is binary stream of tar.gz and I can not get the right format from the web. The stream can only be sotred as plain with messy codes. It is supposed as : I used the Dispostion  and application/x-tar-gz. I print the stream to the stdin and the stream will be store as filename.tar.gz. But no really. Some wrong with the head? With your method, I can print some  messy codes about  half of the file size. But I can not decompress it as a regular compressed file.  I read the disposition specification and found no problems about the head. God~